# Find the distance between the two parallel planes.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the distance between the two parallel planes?

$$a: x-2y+3z-2=0$$
$$b: 2x-4y+6z-1=0$$

The given answer is: $\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{56}}$

Comment: You can follow the same method given in [this example](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ronmiech/Calculus_Problems/32A/chap11/section5/718d65/718_65.html).

Comment: You can read the signed distances of the planes from the origin directly from these equations. Their difference is the distance between the planes.

Answer (score 2):

Take a point in the plane $(a) $.

for example $A (2,0,0) $.

the distance to the plane $(b) $ is

$$\frac {|2.2- 4.0 +6.0-1|}{ \sqrt {2^2+4^2+6^2   } }=$$
$$\frac {3}{\sqrt {56}} $$

Answer (score 0):

converting the equation of one plane into the Hessian normal form we get
$$\frac{x-2y+3x-2}{\pm \sqrt{1+4+9}}=0$$ and taking a Point from the other plane, for.e.g $$P(\frac{1}{2};0;0)$$ plugging this in the Hessian form we get
$$\frac{\frac{3}{2}}{\sqrt{14}}$$